# Why was sys.modules chosen to be a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-import

When Python wants to import a module it is first going to look in `sys.modules`. But since the key-value pairs of dictionaries are not in a fixed order, how can you ever know for certain which of two identically named modules in `sys.modules` will be imported first?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since it is a mapping, there can *be* no identically named modules in `sys.modules`.

That is the point. If use the statement `import foo` and `sys.modules['foo']` exists, that module is returned. No file access is needed, no top-level code for that module needs to be run.

If `foo` is not present, then the `sys.path` determines where `foo` is going to be found first. That value is a list, so it has order, and the search for the `foo` module is conducted according to that ordering.

Comment: `>>> dict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'b':3}` then `>>> dict` returns `{'a': 1, 'b': 3}`. Me not knowing this stems from my false assumption that I would get an error from the moment I assigned the dictionary if keys were identical. I never went far enough before to print out the actual dictionary again.

Comment: @Bentley4: Even if it _did_ allow multiples… how would the order help you know which one is which? You'd know you want "one of the modules named `foo`", and that there are two of them, and even which one was imported first… but without knowing whether you wanted the one that was imported first, or the one that was imported second, how would that help?

Comment: Btw, the [Python reference](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) says that after `sys.modules` first `sys.meta_path` is searched, only then implicitely defined finders are queried (among them `sys.path`, but it's not clear in what order)

Comment: @Bentley4: Yes, if you've installed any import hooks, they get checked before the path. (Also, in 2.x, it looks for relative imports before checking the path.) I think the last paragraph was just giving a general overview of the basic case, not trying to explain the import process rigorously.

Comment: Yes, I simplified; the process has been updated significantly in the latest Python releases and a complete exhaustive treatise would only serve to confuse.